# Python Twitch bot SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, stream, bots

this is the script my V.Python 3.5.0
        import requests
        import subprocess
        import json
        import sys
        import threading
        import time
        from Queue import Queue
        import urllib3
        import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl

```
    urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
    #urllib3.disable_warnings() unverified HTTPS requests
    numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
    builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
    startTime = time.time()
    numberOfSockets = 0
    concurrent = 25
    urls = []
    urlsUsed = []
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://173.201.183.172:8000',
        'http': 'http://94.181.34.64:81',
    }


    def getURL(): # Get tokens
      output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/swagvyper", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
      return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

    def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
        global numberOfSockets
        global numberOfViewers
        while True:
            if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
                numberOfSockets += 1
                print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
                urls.append(getURL())

    def view(): # Opens connections to send views
        global numberOfSockets
        while True:
            url=q.get()
            # requests.head(url, proxies=proxies)
            requests.head(url) # Sending a HEAD request is enough to count as a view
            if (url in urlsUsed):
                urls.remove(url)
                urlsUsed.remove(url)
                numberOfSockets -= 1
            else:
                urlsUsed.append(url)
            q.task_done()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for i in range(0, builderThreads):
            threading.Thread(target = build).start()

        while True:
            while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are built
                time.sleep(1)

            q=Queue(concurrent*2)
            for i in range(concurrent):
                try:
                    t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                    t.daemon=True
                    t.start()
                except:
                    print 'thread error'
            try:
                for url in urls:
                    print url
                    q.put(url.strip())
                    q.join()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                sys.exit(1)
```

and this is the errow that is shooting me pleass help!

```
      "pythonviwer.py", line 36
            print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
                                ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You will get rid of this particular error if you do `print("Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers))` since you are using Python 3, not Python 2

Comment: Why have you tagged this both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7`? Do you need your code to work with both versions? Are you translating code from one version to the other?

Comment: Formatted error